# dplyr mixing SE and NSE

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation, nse

I am having difficulties in mixing SE and NSE dplyr evaluation in a function.
I have a dataset for which I want to divide each column based on the number of occurrences on a different column.

Let me write a small function with the functionality I am after

```
func <- function(param) {
 mtcars %>%
 group_by(cyl) %>%
 summarise_each(funs_(lazyeval::interp(~sum(.))/lazyeval::interp(~sum(var == 
 0), var = as.name(param))))
 }
```

Function is to be used such as `func(am)` or `func(vs)`

I have tried various alternatives to that function, but none is working.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

In this case it's `funs` that needs to be used in its standard evaluation version (`funs_`). Also, the whole formula goes under one call to `interp`. For example:

```
func <- function(param, data=mtcars) {
  data %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise_each(funs_(lazyeval::interp(~sum(.)/sum(.[var==0]), var = as.name(param))))
}

func("vs")
```

> ```
>     cyl      mpg     disp       hp      drat        wt      qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
> 1     4 11.28077 9.613466 9.989011 10.108352 11.749065 12.605389   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
> 2     6  2.23987 2.759570 2.167089  2.197898  2.640048  2.569212   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
> 3     8  1.00000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   NaN    NA    NA    NA
> ```

Or, a more general function:

```
func <- function(param, param.subset, groupvar, data) {
  data %>%
    group_by_(groupvar) %>%
    summarise_each(funs_(lazyeval::interp(
      ~if(is.numeric(.)) {
        sum(.[var==param.subset])/sum(.)
      } else {
        length(unique(.[var==param.subset]))
      }, var = as.name(param))))
}

func(param="gender", param.subset="Girl", groupvar="grade", data=vcd::JointSports)
```

> ```
>    grade      Freq opinion  year gender
> 1    1st 0.5866477       5     2      1
> 2    3rd 0.6137566       5     2      1
> ```

I still feel like I don't really "get" standard evaluation with dplyr and would be interested in whether there are better approaches than the code above.